# JPEG Load/Save to/from rgba via Win32 API in C via grid32

Tags: c, winapi, jpeg, gdi

I want to be able to load/save jpeg files on Windows via api, specifically gdi32.dll because it looks to universally exist in all versions of Windows.

But I'm unable to find any information on how to do this from an array of pixels with 4 bytes per color (rgba, bgra, rgb would be ok to since jpeg doesn't support alpha etc.)

Not interested in an external library or gdi+.  gdi32 should have the ability, but I can't seem to find enough information on how to implement it.

Comment: Why on earth can't you use gdiplus? You would be hard pressed to find any Windows system that doesn't have gdiplus.

Answer (score 2):

Plain GDI does not have any support for JPEG.

If you won't countenance using a library other than GDI, then you will have to write your own JPEG library. Allow me to recommend that you reconsider your requirements.

Comment: No 3rd party library required. The [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654.aspx) ships with every supported Windows platform.

Comment: @IInspeectable That's not gdi

Comment: Correct, but it's not a 3rd party library either, as you initially claimed. It's a 1st party library that ships with Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I was sloppy there

Answer (score 2):

I am going to ignore your refusal to use anything outside of gdi32.dll, because that kind of requirement is not likely to help anyone, and as @David Heffernan said, there is no JPEG support in gdi32.dll.

There are a number of ways to load/save JPEG pictures built into winapi, and supported all the way back to Windows 2000 (and earlier...).

1. [`OleLoadPicture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [`OleSavePicture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - though I am not sure if it's very easy to save your own JPEG files this way.
2. [`Gdiplus::Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows loading & saving JPEG files.

Answer (score 1):

The GDI is the *Graphical Device Interface*. It's responsibility includes rendering primitives to the screen or offscreen device contexts. Encoders and decoders are not included.

The standard Windows encoders and decoders are provided through the [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654.aspx). This component is available starting with Windows XP SP2. It is also available for Windows Store apps.